# Development of spark streaming using pyspark but not getting expected result

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

I am new in spark streaming. I developed a small spark streaming application.
Here want to read a files from the directory and print the output to the console
(Or to the text file)

Below is code i developed in python

```
**import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
sc = SparkContext(appName='PysparkStreaming')
ssc = StreamingContext(sc,3)
lines= ssc.textFileStream('file:///home/cloudera/spark/logs/')
counts=lines.flatMap(lambda line :line.split(" ")).map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey( lambda a, b: a + b)
counts.pprint()
print(counts)
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()**
```

While running the code like

```
spark-submit as_log_stream.py
```

Getting below warnings continues every 3 seconds as declared in stream but expected output is not displaying which is word count.
Could you please let me know what wrong here it will be very helpfull?

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/parquet/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/avro/avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.13.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
18/12/10 02:01:36 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
18/12/10 02:01:38 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/12/10 02:01:39 WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, quickstart.cloudera resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.186.133 instead (on interface eth1)
18/12/10 02:01:39 WARN util.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
18/12/10 02:01:40 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: cloudera
18/12/10 02:01:40 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: cloudera
18/12/10 02:01:40 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(cloudera); users with modify permissions: Set(cloudera)
18/12/10 02:01:40 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 50432.
18/12/10 02:01:41 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
18/12/10 02:01:41 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
18/12/10 02:01:42 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@192.168.186.133:45299]
18/12/10 02:01:42 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@192.168.186.133:45299]
18/12/10 02:01:42 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 45299.
18/12/10 02:01:42 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
18/12/10 02:01:42 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
18/12/10 02:01:42 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-78e8d300-dbad-4008-a4ec-339f3599d8a1
18/12/10 02:01:42 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 534.5 MB
18/12/10 02:01:43 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
18/12/10 02:01:44 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
18/12/10 02:01:44 WARN component.AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
    at org.spark-project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.org$apache$spark$ui$JettyUtils$$httpConnect$1(JettyUtils.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$$anonfun$7.apply(JettyUtils.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$$anonfun$7.apply(JettyUtils.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:2040)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:2032)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.startJettyServer(JettyUtils.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.bind(WebUI.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$14.apply(SparkContext.scala:489)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$14.apply(SparkContext.scala:489)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:489)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18/12/10 02:01:44 WARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
18/12/10 02:01:44 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4041
18/12/10 02:01:44 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4041.
18/12/10 02:01:44 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.186.133:4041
18/12/10 02:01:46 INFO util.Utils: Copying /home/cloudera/practice/spark/scripts/as_log_stream.py to /tmp/spark-a57a538e-e7c7-496b-ad88-8d968ac379e8/userFiles-b449f5bb-434a-47d7-a5bc-ca9eb3f9e001/as_log_stream.py
18/12/10 02:01:46 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added file file:/home/cloudera/practice/spark/scripts/as_log_stream.py at file:/home/cloudera/practice/spark/scripts/as_log_stream.py with timestamp 1544436106336
18/12/10 02:01:48 INFO executor.Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
18/12/10 02:01:48 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 35274.
18/12/10 02:01:48 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 35274
18/12/10 02:01:48 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
18/12/10 02:01:48 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:35274 with 534.5 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 35274)
18/12/10 02:01:48 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
18/12/10 02:01:51 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Duration for remembering RDDs set to 60000 ms for org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream@326a8451
<pyspark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream object at 0x1111f90>
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.ForEachDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO python.PythonTransformedDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.MappedDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Slide time = 3000 ms
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Remember duration = 60000 ms
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream@326a8451
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.MappedDStream: Slide time = 3000 ms
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.MappedDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.MappedDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.MappedDStream: Remember duration = 3000 ms
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.MappedDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream@1b8496f
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO python.PythonTransformedDStream: Slide time = 3000 ms
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO python.PythonTransformedDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO python.PythonTransformedDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO python.PythonTransformedDStream: Remember duration = 3000 ms
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO python.PythonTransformedDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonTransformedDStream@69dd174a
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.ForEachDStream: Slide time = 3000 ms
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.ForEachDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.ForEachDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.ForEachDStream: Remember duration = 3000 ms
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO dstream.ForEachDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@32243192
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO util.RecurringTimer: Started timer for JobGenerator at time 1544436114000
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO scheduler.JobGenerator: Started JobGenerator at 1544436114000 ms
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Started JobScheduler
18/12/10 02:01:52 INFO streaming.StreamingContext: StreamingContext started
18/12/10 02:01:54 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 74 ms
18/12/10 02:01:54 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: New files at time 1544436114000 ms:

18/12/10 02:01:55 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1544436114000 ms
18/12/10 02:01:55 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1544436114000 ms.0 from job set of time 1544436114000 ms
18/12/10 02:01:55 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393
18/12/10 02:01:55 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 3 (call at /usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1724)
18/12/10 02:01:55 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393) with 1 output partitions
18/12/10 02:01:55 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393)
18/12/10 02:01:55 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 0)
18/12/10 02:01:55 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
18/12/10 02:01:55 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1 (PythonRDD[7] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43), which has no missing parents
18/12/10 02:01:57 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 51 ms
18/12/10 02:01:57 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: New files at time 1544436117000 ms:

18/12/10 02:01:57 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 5.9 KB, free 534.5 MB)
18/12/10 02:01:57 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1544436117000 ms
18/12/10 02:01:57 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.5 KB, free 534.5 MB)
18/12/10 02:01:57 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:35274 (size: 3.5 KB, free: 534.5 MB)
18/12/10 02:01:57 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1004
18/12/10 02:01:57 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (PythonRDD[7] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
18/12/10 02:01:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 1 tasks
18/12/10 02:01:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1963 bytes)
18/12/10 02:01:57 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 0)
18/12/10 02:01:57 INFO executor.Executor: Fetching file:/home/cloudera/practice/spark/scripts/as_log_stream.py with timestamp 1544436106336
18/12/10 02:01:57 INFO util.Utils: /home/cloudera/practice/spark/scripts/as_log_stream.py has been previously copied to /tmp/spark-a57a538e-e7c7-496b-ad88-8d968ac379e8/userFiles-b449f5bb-434a-47d7-a5bc-ca9eb3f9e001/as_log_stream.py
18/12/10 02:01:57 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 0 blocks
18/12/10 02:01:57 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 34 ms
18/12/10 02:01:59 INFO python.PythonRunner: Times: total = 1902, boot = 1608, init = 119, finish = 175
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO python.PythonRunner: Times: total = 5, boot = -70, init = 75, finish = 0
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 36 ms
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: New files at time 1544436120000 ms:

18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 0). 1213 bytes result sent to driver
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1544436120000 ms
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 0) in 2725 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/1)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393) finished in 2.854 s
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393, took 5.008004 s
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2018-12-10 02:01:54
-------------------------------------------

18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1544436114000 ms.0 from job set of time 1544436114000 ms
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Total delay: 6.455 s for time 1544436114000 ms (execution: 5.270 s)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1544436117000 ms.0 from job set of time 1544436117000 ms
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Cleared 0 old files that were older than 1544436054000 ms: 
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 11 (call at /usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1724)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393) with 1 output partitions
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 3 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 2)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 3 (PythonRDD[22] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43), which has no missing parents
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches ArrayBuffer()
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 5.9 KB, free 534.5 MB)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata: 
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.5 KB, free 534.5 MB)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on localhost:35274 (size: 3.5 KB, free: 534.5 MB)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1004
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 3 (PythonRDD[22] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 3.0 with 1 tasks
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1963 bytes)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 1)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 0 blocks
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO python.PythonRunner: Times: total = 42, boot = -574, init = 616, finish = 0
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO python.PythonRunner: Times: total = 44, boot = 6, init = 38, finish = 0
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 1). 1213 bytes result sent to driver
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 3 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393) finished in 0.115 s
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393, took 0.190777 s
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 1) in 128 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/1)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 3.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2018-12-10 02:01:57
-------------------------------------------

18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1544436117000 ms.0 from job set of time 1544436117000 ms
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Total delay: 3.815 s for time 1544436117000 ms (execution: 0.335 s)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1544436120000 ms.0 from job set of time 1544436120000 ms
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO python.PythonRDD: Removing RDD 6 from persistence list
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO rdd.MapPartitionsRDD: Removing RDD 1 from persistence list
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 18 (call at /usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1724)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 2 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393) with 1 output partitions
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 5 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 4)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 5 (PythonRDD[23] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43), which has no missing parents
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 6
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Cleared 0 old files that were older than 1544436057000 ms: 
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches ArrayBuffer()
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata: 
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 5.9 KB, free 534.5 MB)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 1
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.5 KB, free 534.5 MB)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on localhost:35274 (size: 3.5 KB, free: 534.5 MB)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1004
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 5 (PythonRDD[23] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 5.0 with 1 tasks
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1963 bytes)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 2)
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 0 blocks
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
18/12/10 02:02:00 INFO python.PythonRunner: Times: total = 41, boot = -103, init = 144, finish = 0
18/12/10 02:02:01 INFO python.PythonRunner: Times: total = 56, boot = 22, init = 34, finish = 0
18/12/10 02:02:01 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 2). 1213 bytes result sent to driver
18/12/10 02:02:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 5 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393) finished in 0.128 s
18/12/10 02:02:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 2 finished: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393, took 0.174702 s
18/12/10 02:02:01 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 2) in 129 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/1)
18/12/10 02:02:01 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 5.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2018-12-10 02:02:00
-------------------------------------------

18/12/10 02:02:01 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1544436120000 ms.0 from job set of time 1544436120000 ms
18/12/10 02:02:01 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Total delay: 1.045 s for time 1544436120000 ms (execution: 0.230 s)
18/12/10 02:02:01 INFO python.PythonRDD: Removing RDD 14 from persistence list
18/12/10 02:02:01 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 14
18/12/10 02:02:01 INFO rdd.MapPartitionsRDD: Removing RDD 9 from persistence list
18/12/10 02:02:01 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 9
18/12/10 02:02:01 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Cleared 0 old files that were older than 1544436060000 ms: 
18/12/10 02:02:01 INFO scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches ArrayBuffer()
18/12/10 02:02:01 INFO scheduler.InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata:
```

Script used to generate the file: which is working as expected.

```
from  random import randint
import time
def main():
    createFile()
def createFile():
    print('creating files')
    with open('//home//cloudera//practice//spark//source//server_log_name_12_0008.log', 'r') as logfile:
        loglines=logfile.readlines()
        linecount=0
        while linecount <=70:
            totalline = len(loglines)
            linenumber = randint(0,totalline -10)
            with open('//home//cloudera//spark//logs//log{0}.txt'.format(linecount),'w') as writefile:
                writefile.write(' '.join(line for line in loglines[linenumber:totalline]))
                print('creating file log{0}.txt'.format(linecount))
                linecount+=1
                time.sleep(2)

__name__ == '__main__'
main()
```

Observation: can see the files add in spark streaming log and getting output set to the driver. which driver the output sent? How I can collect the output in file? please suggest

```
18/12/12 17:22:10 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 4611 ms
18/12/12 17:22:10 WARN dstream.FileInputDStream: Time taken to find new files exceeds the batch size. Consider increasing the batch size or reducing the number of files in the monitored directory.
18/12/12 17:22:10 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: New files at time 1544664126000 ms:

18/12/12 17:22:11 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1544664126000 ms
18/12/12 17:22:11 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 53 ms
**18/12/12 17:22:11 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: New files at time 1544664129000 ms:
file:/home/cloudera/practice/spark/logs/log0.txt
file:/home/cloudera/practice/spark/logs/log1.txt**
18/12/12 17:22:11 INFO python.PythonRunner: Times: total = 9183, boot = 8301, init = 262, finish = 620
18/12/12 17:22:11 INFO python.PythonRunner: Times: total = 39, boot = 38, init = 1, finish = 0
**18/12/12 17:22:11 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 0). 1213 bytes result sent to driver**
18/12/12 17:22:12 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 0) in 9720 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/1)
18/12/12 17:22:12 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393) finished in 9.797 s
18/12/12 17:22:12 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
18/12/12 17:22:12 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393, took 11.534252 s
```

Comment: Please confirm you haven't added any files to the directory after the spark streaming job started.

Comment: Also, please make sure you're not using HDFS (Hadoop File System).

Comment: did you try out the provided solution? You should accept it if it solved your issue, provide more feedback or your own solution. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Alexandre Jama I added a files to the directory. still not getting I modified the question and added the scriptt which i am using to generate the file which working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

My first take is that you're not adding any new files to `file:///home/cloudera/spark/logs/` while your spark streaming program is running.

`textFileStream` only picks up new data after your job starts. After the your job is running, try copying some files to the directory.

Also, are you sure you're not working with HDFS? I see Cloudera and Spark, so that usually means Hadoop. If so, you need to make sure you're `hdfs://home/cloudera/spark/logs` or if you don't have your Hadoop Namenode configured, it should be `hdfs://host:port/home/cloudera/spark/logs/`

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. I have a separate script to add the files to the logs directory and my end to end aim is to read a continues files from a directory and load to the other files in between I have to convert unstructured file to csv file. but I struct here its self